# ng bootstrap 4 - typeahead open on focus

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I use ng-bootstrap 4 (beta 8). At the moment i have this:

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
    {{ r.label }}
</ng-template>

<input
        id="typeahead-focus"
        class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="model"
        [ngbTypeahead]="search"
        [inputFormatter]="formatter"
        [resultTemplate]="rt"
        (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
        (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)"
        #instance="ngbTypeahead"
/>
```

Now, I want to open typeahead, if the user click in the input element. How can I do this?

```
this.search = (text$) =>
    text$
        .map(term => (term === '' ? this.items : this.items.filter(v => v.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10));

this.formatter = (x: {label: string}) => {
    console.log(x);
    return x.label;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following solution works for me:

Add  `onFocus` event to your input search

my.html file

```
 <input 
    (focus)="onFocus($event)" 
    type="text" 
    (selectItem)="onItemSelected($event)" 
    [(ngModel)]="myModel" 
    [ngbTypeahead]="search" 
    [resultTemplate]="rt" 
    [inputFormatter]="formatter"/>
```

my.ts file

```
  public onFocus(e: Event): void {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setTimeout(() => {
      const inputEvent: Event = new Event('input');
      e.target.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
    }, 0);
  }

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(200)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .map(term => this.myList
          .filter(v => this.myfilter(term))
          .slice(0, 10));
```

Also take a look at [Typeahed: allow search on focus #698](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/698)

Comment: so much simpler than creating all these subjects, instances and such, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to current [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#focus) you can use html :

```
<input id="typeahead-focus" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model"  [ngbTypeahead]="search" (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)" (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)" #instance="ngbTypeahead"/>
```

and code:

```
  @ViewChild('instance') instance: NgbTypeahead;
  focus$ = new Subject<string>();
  click$ = new Subject<string>();

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

  return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
    map(term => (term === '' ? states
       : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
  );
```